# c++ Boost Multithread CPU and Memory Usages are slow and high - need help

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using boost library to create multithread with mutex. I based on some example on google. The multitrheads are working fine, but CPU are 100%, memory usage from task manager are 300K+. My two multithread functions are performed very high data conversion and analysis. I am not sure if I missed somethings. Here are the part of my multithread:

```
wait(1); 
mutex.lock();
boost::thread t1(&YExcel::BasicExcelCell::TTiTraceParserConv,c,TTiAsciiTraceOutputDL.GetBuffer(0));
mutex.unlock();
wait(2); 
mutex.lock();
boost::thread t2(&YExcel::BasicExcelCell::TTiTraceParserConv,c,TTiAsciiTraceOutputUL.GetBuffer(0));
mutex.unlock();
t1.join();
t2.join();
wait(2); 

wait(1); 
mutex.lock();
boost::thread t5(&YExcel::BasicExcelCell::UeAndCellParamParseUL,c,TTiAsciiTraceOutputUL.GetBuffer(0), NumOfLinesUL,GHOSTFILTER);
mutex.unlock();
wait(2); 
mutex.lock();
boost::thread t6(&YExcel::BasicExcelCell::UeAndCellParamParseDL,c,TTiAsciiTraceOutputDL.GetBuffer(0), NumOfLinesDL);
mutex.unlock();
t5.join();
t6.join();
```

Do I need to do somethings inside those functions? Thanks in advance. I was tested with Dell Optilex 745 Pentium D. I am not sure it supports Multi-thread. I had printed hard_concurrent, it showed on 1.

One of the function - summary

```
int BasicExcelCell::UeAndCellParamParseDL(char *inname, int NumOfRecords)
{
typedef boost::tokenizer <boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > my_tokenizer;   
....
....
CString TTiAsciiTraceOutput(inname);
TTiAsciiTraceOutput.Replace(".dat","_raw.txt");

ifstream infile(TTiAsciiTraceOutput.GetBuffer(0));
if (!infile)
{
    cout << "Couldn't open file " << TTiAsciiTraceOutput.GetBuffer(0) << " for reading." << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
cout << "\nOpened file " << TTiAsciiTraceOutput.GetBuffer(0) << " for reading." << endl << endl;

int lineCount=0;
getline(infile, line);
if (NumOfRecords < 0)
{
    cout<<"Number Of Lines to be parsed is not specified!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
while (getline(infile, line) && lineCount <= NumOfRecords)
{       
    lineCount++;
    int FoundCrntiEmpty=0;

    my_tokenizer tok(line);
    int i = 0;

    for (my_tokenizer::iterator it(tok.begin()), end(tok.end()); it != end; ++it)
    { 
        mystr.push_back(*it);
    }

    int tokcount=0;
    int SingleTx=0;
    int TxDiv=0;
    int tokCountFlag=0;
    double MetricCalTemp=0.0;

    for (vector < string >::iterator mit(mystr.begin()); mit != mystr.end(); mit++)
    {
        for (vector < string >::iterator _mit(mystr.begin()); _mit != mystr.end(); _mit++)
        {
            tokCountFlag++;
            if (tokCountFlag==60)
                break;//not need to goto the whole iterator

            switch (tokCountFlag)
            {
                case 29: 
                     <<*_mit<<endl; 
                        if (*_mit=="0")
                            FoundCrntiEmpty=1;
                    break;

                case 58:
                    //cout<<"Single or Tx " <<*_mit<<endl;

                    if (*_mit == "0")
                        SingleTx=1;
                    else if (*_mit == "1")
                        TxDiv=1;

                    break;
            }
        } 
       }
 }
```

Another short function on first thread:

```
void BasicExcelCell::TTiTraceParserConv(char *p_resFile)
{

char ttiTraceParser[512];
char ttiTraceConfig[512];
char cwd[512];

size_t size;

char OrigDLFile[512];

GetModuleFileName(NULL, cwd, 512);
char * CollectTTiTraceAdvance_exe;
CollectTTiTraceAdvance_exe = strstr (cwd,"CollectTTiTraceAdvance.exe");
strncpy (CollectTTiTraceAdvance_exe,"",26);

CString TTiAsciiTraceOutput(p_resFile);
CString ParserExe, TraceConfig;

ParserExe.Format(_T("%s\\BinaryFileParser\\tti_trace_parser_wmp.exe "),cwd);

sprintf(OrigDLFile,"%s",TTiAsciiTraceOutput.GetBuffer(0));
TTiAsciiTraceOutput.Replace(".dat","_raw.txt");
TraceConfig.Format(_T(" %s\\%s %s\\%s"),cwd,OrigDLFile,cwd,TTiAsciiTraceOutput);

cout<<"\n\n****Prepare to generate RawFile!!!"<<endl;
ShellAndWait(ParserExe.GetBuffer(0),TraceConfig.GetBuffer(0),"WAIT",240,1);//4 minutes

ParserExe.ReleaseBuffer(0);
TraceConfig.ReleaseBuffer(0);
}
```

Comment: `but CPU are 100%`.  Congratulations, it works.

Comment: I get worried whenever I see `wait()` calls in a multithreaded program; are those calls there for your own education, or because they are 'required' for the program's correct execution? Furthermore, based on how you're using the `mutex.lock()` and `.unlock()` calls, I've got a feeling you're not locking your data correctly, either. I strongly suggest trying some of the [guides on using Boost threading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415994/boost-thread-tutorials) for a coherent start-to-finish view of threading. (I can't say that this code is _wrong_, but it doesn't look _right_.)

Comment: Is `CString` MFC?  I think you're using `GetBuffer` more than necessary, it's error prone and only needed when you're modifying the contents.  Try a simple implicit or explicit `(const char*)` cast first.  Also, I prefer `std::string` for consistency with STL and Boost, and for general portability.

Comment: Since you're already using Boost, take a look at `BOOST_FOREACH`, you could make your loops and array access clearer.

Comment: If you make better use of `const`, e.g., in the parameter for `UeAndCellParamParseDL` you will be able to make more natural use of both `std::string` and `CString` without the need for casting or `GetBuffer`.

Comment: I plan to make my tool portable to both linux and window. For now, I  mixed with everything, not cleaned and organized. I will clean up and make it more readable. For me, it is still long way to learn C++. Thanks, Tim for taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
mutex.lock();
boost::thread t6(...);
mutex.unlock();
```

This only protects the creation of the thread from running concurrently with anything else, it has no effect on the operations carried out by that thread.  You'll need to lock the mutex from within the thread function to gain any protection.

In addition, as pointed out in the comments, the `wait`s are suspicious and should not be needed.

Finally, you should (in my opinion) never use mutex.lock/mutex.unlock directly because it's error-prone, *especially* in the presence of exceptions.  Use the RAII tools such as `scoped_lock` which are provided by Boost.

To get any more information, you'll have to show us what those thread functions are actually doing.

Comment: First time to use multi-thread, at least it works luckily:-) and I am totally agreed with all "it does not look right me too". For mutex, I just put in there to see how it behaves. I will post part of my functions on the main post. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: In the mean time, I will read the thread manual. Thanks again.

Comment: I see a few potential issues. It looks like `mystr` is a class member and all your threads are running methods of the same class instance.  Any class members accessed from multiple threads are potential problems.  Also, a file opened from multiple threads could cause problems, but I can't tell whether that is happening without knowing what values are being used for the various parameters.  If if nothing is being shared between threads, or all the threads treat the shared data as strictly read-only, then no mutexes are needed.  Same with files, as long as each thread opens its own file handle.

Comment: Thanks for some advises.  For this TTiTraceParserConv function, it did not take much CPU and memory, but one small issue if I don't add some wait timeout, one of thread won't finish executing all the statements.  It seemed it exited itself in the middle. I can see from the screen. But if I add Wait(1-2) seconds, it is ok. Any advise on this? For other function, I will try to play around inside function instead of main(). Since it worked fine. Even with one thread, memory usage around 200K+. Those conversion parsed a big data file 65K of lines (30Megs) 30-50 seconds. I can live with it.

Comment: The only reason I can see that `TTiTraceParserConv` would return early is that the program it's shelling out to exits before you expect, assuming that `ShellAndWait` is working correctly, anyway.